# Whitespace after number subscript

Tags: formatting, fonts

When I write something like this:

```
(Subscript[x, 0], f(Subscript[x, 0]))
```

I get some undesirable whitespace after each of the `Subscript[x, 0]`. The whitespace disappears or is at least significantly reduced, if I write e.g. `Subscript[x, i]` instead.

This is a screen shot of the problem:

[image: Screen shot]

I have looked around the object inspector for a solution, but I haven't found one. 
It appears to be a font specific problem: If I use `Times` - the problem goes away, but for most other fonts - it is there (I use `Georgia`).

The raw cell looks like this:

```
Cell[TextData[Cell[BoxData[
 FormBox[
  RowBox[{"(", 
   RowBox[{
    SubscriptBox["x", "0"], ",", 
    RowBox[{"f", "(", 
     SubscriptBox["x", "0"], ")"}]}], ")"}], TraditionalForm]],
 FormatType->"TraditionalForm"]], "Text",
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.590903299361623*^9, 3.590903306745799*^9}}]
```

Comment: Can you post a screen grab so we can see this whitespace.

Comment: I think we need more information. I think it would be useful if you were to edit your question to show what the raw cell looks like. That is, please use cmd-shift+E on the cell with the offending expression and then copy and paste what that displays into your question,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these sorts of cases you could either introduce a `\[NegativeVeryThinSpace]` or `\[NegativeThinSpace]` (For the latter Esc - space bar space bar Esc)

```
Cell[TextData[Cell[BoxData[
 FormBox[
  RowBox[{"(", 
   RowBox[{
    SubscriptBox["x", "0"], 
    "\[NegativeThinSpace]", ",", 
    RowBox[{"f", "(", 
     SubscriptBox["x", "0"], ")"}]}], ")"}], 
  TraditionalForm]]]], "Text"
  ]
```

[image]

Alternatively you could nudge characters to the right or left as needed. For example highlight the comma and from the main menu go to **Insert > Typesetting > Nudge Left**. This introduces an adjustment box:

```
Cell[TextData[Cell[BoxData[
 FormBox[
  RowBox[{"(", 
   RowBox[{
    SubscriptBox["x", "i"], 
    AdjustmentBox[",",
     BoxMargins->{{-0.14058209774848984`, 
      0.14058209774848984`}, {0., 0.}}], 
    RowBox[{"f", "(", 
     SubscriptBox["x", "i"], ")"}]}], ")"}], 
  TraditionalForm]]]], "Text"]
```

[image]